# Foreign constraint failed add record sqlite3 using many to many relationship

Tags: django, sqlite

My models:

```
class TestSkill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)



class Girl(models.Model):
   skills = models.ManyToManyField(TestSkill)
```

this has created following sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_app_girl_skills" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "girl_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "my_app_girl" ("id"), "testskill_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "my_app_testskill" ("id"))
```

And after I tried manually to create a row in db using sql lite browser I 've got an error:
`Foreign constraint failed`

Comment: And what's exactly the problem? Have you `./manage.py makemigrations` and then `./manage.py migrate` after creating `TestSkill` and `Girl` ??

Comment: @nik_m yes I made migrations and migrated

Comment: @nik_m see update, I 've just somehow missed part of the question( because of this I don't know exact text of error now(